# Porque desaparecen objetos procedure en genexus ev3?

Tags: genexus, genexusxev3

Estoy trabajando con Gx Ev3+java y en determiando momento desaparecieron objetos procedure. No se pudo haber borrado manualmente porque están referenciado en otros objetos, por lo que gx no lo permitiría. Están referenciados como objeto.call(). Si Alquien tuvo la misma experiencia por favor compartirla.

Comment: Cuando dices que "desaparecieron": es que no los ves en el "folder view" (en el árbol de los mismos) o directamente en el Open Object (Control+O) no aparecen.
La pregunta viene porque si no aparecen en el folder view el problema puede que sea que dependen de un "objeto padre" (folder o módulo) que tiene problemas. Pero si ni siquiera aparecen en el Ctrl+O parece que efectivamente se borraron.
Puede servir esta extensión para recuperar objetos borrados (https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?16039,Recover+Object+Extension,)

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.